Arquillian: add datasource to deployment
From Arquillian docs, I read that you can return a Descriptor to add a datasource to a deployment.
I could not find the DataSourceDescriptor class though.
@Deployment(order = 1)
public static Descriptor createDep1()
{
    return Descriptors.create(DataSourceDescriptor.class);
}

Digging around, I found that org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptor/test/ironjacamar/DataSourcesTestCase.java uses  "org.jboss.datasources.api.DatasourcesDescriptor".
However, I could not find the maven repo for this class. Any ideas?
